# Get warning for undefined Angular bindings

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm using Angular 1.4.6.  This question is simple.

```
<button class="button fa fa-angle-left"
        ng-click="vm.dequeueSelected()"
        ng-disabled="!vm.rightGridHasSelection"></button>
```

Okay, here I have a button with two bindings to my controller scope.  Right now, my code has many of these bindings where the `vm` doesn't contain the bound property.  In this example, my controller hasn't set `rightGridHasSelection` on the scope.

This is silently ignored by Angular.  I find this behavior undesirable and would like a warning instead.

How can I make Angular issue a warning when the bound property is undefined?  Can the `ngBind` directive be decorated?

**Edit**

I understand that tests are the right way to go about this.  This is not an option for me because of policy set by management.  I need some way to detect all of the bindings in my view that aren't getting set by the controller.  There must be a way to do this.

Comment: isn't that what tests are for? Would have a ton of warnings when data is asynchronous

Comment: angular runs this as an expression though. As far as angular is concerned, there is no problem. Your button will be disabled if `rightGridHasSelection` is false or undefined/null

Comment: @charlietfl, my company doesn't like the time "wasted" on writing unit tests.  I'm trying to develop a rather large page with lots of these bindings.  Can I make Angular issue a warning when the bound property is undefined?

Comment: in your `ng-disabled` attribute, you can pass a function rather than a property. In your controller, use the function to return true/false and if false, throw your warning

Comment: my guess is probably not very easily and would be more time consuming and less performant than writing tests

Comment: That doesn't answer the question.  What if the function is unbound?

Comment: how would the function be unbound if you wrote the function?

Comment: I agree @charlietfl.  I've spent enough energy clashing with management on the writing of tests though.  The bigwigs have spoken.

Comment: @Ronnie, you're just moving the problem from an unbound property to an unbound function.  It's the same issue.  I want a warning when the property is undefined.

Comment: @Ronnie I think what she means is if the function doesn't exist that is being referenced from the view

Comment: The function wouldn't be unbound. The function checks if the property is set

Comment: You're missing my point.  I'm trying to track down bindings that aren't being set in the controller.  If I move my bindings from properties to functions, I *still* need to check that the functions are bound by the controller.  That doesn't buy me anything.

Comment: This question applies equally to both of the bindings in my example.  I have a function bound and a property bound.  This question applies to both situations equally.

Comment: Ok, maybe I am not understanding what you are asking. Consider this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/1drtj85x/2/ try changing the value from true to false and also commenting it out.

Comment: Remove the `isPropSet` function, or put a typo in the name.  The code will execute with no issues.  I want a warning issued when the function isn't set.

Comment: This may be possible by using ParseProvider to decorate the Parse service.

Comment: @user1620220, that might be exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: You will probably have to configure `$interpolate` to not fail silently. See this post: http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/05/27/debugging-angularjs-data-binding.aspx

Comment: How about creating a directive that will check all "ng-" attributes of the attached element?

Answer (score 0):

How about creating a custom directive for that? something like:

```
.directive('undefinedCheck', function () {
    return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function($scope, element, attrs, controller) {
      for(var i = 0; i<element[0].attributes.length;i++)
      {      
          var excluded = 'ng-pristine ng-valid'
          if (element[0].attributes[i].value
              && excluded !==element[0].attributes[i].value
              && !$scope[element[0].attributes[i].value])
          {
             alert(element[0].attributes[i].value+ " is undefined");
          }
        }
      }
    }
})
```

and then add it to your element like this:

```
<button undefined-check class="button fa fa-angle-left"
    ng-click="vm.dequeueSelected()"
    ng-disabled="!vm.rightGridHasSelection"></button>
```

[Working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sf96pdqq/2/)